# Артефакты при изменении частоты дискретизации WAV файла

Tags: python, аудио, scipy, wav, цос

Реализую изменение частоты дискретизации WAV файла в кратное число раз на Python. Проблема появилась при реализации потоковой обработки файла. При обработке файла целиком такой проблемы не возникает, ниже представлен код и скриншоты спектра в Adobe Audition. Что делать на стыках обработанных блоков?

```
    wav_read = wave.open(openFileName, 'rb')  # открытие файла для чтения
    wav_write = wave.open(saveFileName, 'wb')  # открытие файла для записи
    nframes = wav_read.getnframes()  # количество отсчетов в файле
    N_BLOCK = nframes // BLOCK_SIZE  # количество блоков в файле
    END_BLOCK = nframes % BLOCK_SIZE  # количество отсчетов в последнем блоке

    for lz in range(N_BLOCK):  
        read_block = wav_read.readframes(BLOCK_SIZE)  # прочесть BLOCK_SIZE отсчетов
        read_block_resample = signal.resample_poly(read_block, kUp, kDown, window=('kaiser', coeff_kaiser))
        wav_write.writeframesraw(read_block_resample)

    wav_read.close()
    wav_write.close()
```

[image: Спектр до]
[image: Спектр после]

[image: Вот что происходит на стыке блоков]

Comment: `readframesraw()` существует? Или чем объясняется неконсистентность вызовов? Так же не очень ясно, что именно задаёт block size. И ешё, битность и количество каналов правильно учитываете?

Comment: block size - размер блока для обработки за одну итерацию цикла. Битность и количество каналов учитываются правильно, программа была отлажена без обработки по блокам. Сейчас пробую на монофайлах внедрить ее для начала. Про "readframesraw() существует? Или чем объясняется неконсистентность вызовов?" не совсем понял.